# Form input to database and reuse in multiple iframes

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, iframe

I have a php form that sends input data to mysql via a processing php page, for example, process.php - and that works just dandy.

However, the process.php page then  redirects the user to another page  http://anotherpage.html">. This new page contains several iframes, which in turn loads pages content 1,2,3,4 in the iframes etc.

My question is, how best do I code this so that the values chosen in the form determine which iframes are loaded? For example, say a user selects "cars" from  drop-down list 1, and "bananas" from drop down list 2 (these vars for example: $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];and $fruit = $_POST['fruit'];) - I want them to see only the iframes that have content relating to cars and bananas. I know there are probably several ways to to this, but it's driving me nuts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 3 Hail Marys for the best answer.

Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving data in database (as you have said - using process.php) than you don't need to use `$_POST['vehicle'];` and `$_POST['fruit'];`.

Get data from database and according to that load your iframe.

Comment: Thanks TechnoKnol, your quick reply is much appreciated.

Comment: is your question solved ? if yes, then `mark question as sovled`